# Twilio 15 Seconds Request Limit

Tags: php, twilio

Twilio has a limit of 15 sec that it waits for a request to any URL https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/11200. Is There a way to increase this limit to something higher?

Comment: Twililo evangelist here.

Unfortuantely there is no way to change the request timeout.  Can I ask whats causing you to need a longer timeout?

Hoipe that helps.

Comment: Well 15 Sec should be long enough since you will think that anything that takes longer than 15 sec is unacceptable specially if you are connecting live calls, I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it just to test something. But thanks for the answer

Comment: Azure Function cold start time can be problematic with the 15 second timeout

Comment: @DevinRader, Has this been enabled since? I would like to be able to increase the timeout for debugging purposes. If I place a breakpoint in my code, I need to act very quickly if I don't want the call to error.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a timeout is encountered if there is no response within that time. Your response may take longer than 15 seconds in which case it depends on how the server is configured on whether or not it will accept the response. When I've configured Apache for example, I had the timeout set to 30 seconds and if nothing at all happened during the 30 seconds, the connection was closed. If however, data was being sent during that time, then the connection would remain open and proceed as expected.

The idea behind the timeout is that you don't want to have a lot of orphaned connections remaining open that do nothing but bog down your server. If you have a long timeout, say 30 or more seconds, and someone uses a script to hammer your server opening many connections, your server could quickly get into a situation where it can't respond to legit connections. Makes it susceptible to attack. In my case I still had some users that were on dial up connections and setting it less than 30 seconds seemed to drop a lot of connections that were actually valid.

If you aren't able to do anything with the connection within 15 seconds I would assume there is something wrong with your setup. Since you have something specific you are wanting to test that apparently needs a longer timeout, you might try contacting the provider to inquire about a different connection mechanism that would allow for a longer timeout. Depending on configuration there may be something that you can pass in during the connection process that enables a longer timeout window. Not very likely but possible. Wouldn't hurt to shoot them an email and ask.